# Best way to make first and last result unique from SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, css

I have an SQL query which outputs 1000 sql entries (sometimes less than 1000). I want the first result and the last result to be unique.

Is the best way to do this, to run it through an IF statement 1000 times, just to customize the first and last row? or is there a better way?

**Example:**

```
$sql=("SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 0, 1000");
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute($executearray);
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

$i = 0;
$total = $q->rowCount();
while ($r = $q->fetch()){

    $i++;

    // first result
    if ($i == 1) {
        echo "<div>" . $r['id'] . "</div>";
        echo "<div>" . $r['image'] . "</div>";
        echo "<div>" . $r['text'] . "</div>";

    // last result
    } elseif ($i == $total) {
        echo "<div>" . $r['somethingelse'] . "</div>";

    // all other results
    } else {
        echo "<div>" . $r['image'] . "</div>";
        echo "<div>" . $r['text'] . "</div>";
    }
}
```

**Is there a way to do something like this...?**

```
$sql=("SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 0, 1000");
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute($executearray);
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

// first result
echo "<div>" . $r[0]['id'] . "</div>";
echo "<div>" . $r[0]['image'] . "</div>";
echo "<div>" . $r[0]['text'] . "</div>";

// results 2-999
while ($i <= $total - 1) {
    echo "<div>" . $r['somethingelse'] . "</div>";
}

// last result
echo "<div>" . $r[$total]['image'] . "</div>";
echo "<div>" . $r[$total]['text'] . "</div>";
```

Comment: `$i++` at the beginning of the loop?

Comment: @webarto: What's wrong with that?

Comment: You've changed your question from a simple color change to a whole new output. If you want drastically different changes than what you're doing is OK.

Comment: @Madmartigan what if you have break/continue inside loop and you want to know how many iterations actually executed.

Comment: @webarto, what if you break out of a loop and you want to know which item you were working on?

Comment: I updated it because I think my example oversimplified what I was trying to ask. The new example should make more sense. It wont work with just CSS.

Comment: @Mikhail `for ($i = 1; $i <= $total; $i++)` ...

Comment: @supercoolville: Since your code works, I wouldn't worry too much about optimization at this level. Running an `if` statement 1000's of times is not a big deal. You should profile your results and see if this is actually worth spending your time and effort on.

Comment: @supercoolville - If you use `for ($i = 2; $i < $total; $i++)` you only loop for the middle records.  Then you can add your header and tail code around it.  See my answer for details.  But note that I think this is such a tiny optimisation that you could have achieved more by working on other parts of your code.

Comment: @supercoolville you can prefetch all your rows into a PHP array, and then handle the first, all-but-last, and last rows, but I betcha that would be slower and require more memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This avoid the IFs for the middle records by looping only for record `2` to `count-1`.

That said, it will only save you a miniscule amount of cpu time.  You'd be better concentrating efforts on expensive code, not something as trivial this.

```
$sql=("SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 0, 1000");
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute($executearray);
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

$i = 0;
$total = $q->rowCount();

// first result
if ($total > 0) {
    $r = $q->fetch();
    echo "<div>" . $r['id'] . "</div>";
    echo "<div>" . $r['image'] . "</div>";
    echo "<div>" . $r['text'] . "</div>";
}

// middle results
for($i=2; $i<$total; $i++){
    $r = $q->fetch();
    echo "<div>" . $r['image'] . "</div>";
    echo "<div>" . $r['text'] . "</div>";
}

// last result
if ($total > 1) {
    $r = $q->fetch();
    echo "<div>" . $r['somethingelse'] . "</div>";
}
```

Also, note that the for loop has an implicit IF in it: `$1<$total`.  Where as your loop was utilising the result from `$q->fetch()` to control the while loop.  I'm even more sceptical as to how much cpu time this will save you.  Without measuring actual cpu cycles it's possible it's not even measurable.

Comment: Ok its about the same speed ... lol. Its 0.1 sec faster on average, based on five 10,000 row tests I ran. I guess Ill just keep the IF's.

Answer (score 3):

You can use smarter CSS selectors such as [:first-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) and [:last-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp)

css:

```
#queryresults p { color: blue }
#queryresults p:first-child { color: red }
#queryresults p:last-child { color: green }
```

html:

```
<div id="queryresults">
<p>result 1</p>
<p>result 2</p>
...
<p>result n-1</p>
<p>result n</p>
</div>
```

Good luck!

Comment: It's actually `red` and `blue` :)

Comment: Thanks :) By the time I realized I made up my own colors the OP changed the question

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
The easiest way to do this would be to alter your `for` or `while` loop when printing out.  I would do this in a `for` loop since a while loop guarantees you'll have at least one result and will always run, but a `for` loop will not run if there are no results.

```
for($i=0; $i<results.length; $i++){
    if($i==0){
       # do unique first thing here
    }elseif($i == results.length){
       # do unique last thing here
    } else {
       # normal
    }
}
```

Or something similar to that.

What do you mean the results to be unique?  you want to style them differently when you print them out in the resulting HTML page?

You can use CSS selectors for this.  `:first-child` and `:last-child`.

See [this entry on quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html) for more details

Comment: I think I oversimplified my example. I updated it. It wont work with just CSS.

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide more details.  You'd want do some testing within the loop that is printing out the results.

Comment: Is there a way to do something like the 2nd example I just added?

Comment: @supercoolville you're already doing it on that example.  I don't see the difference between the two questions though -- I guess in just the order in which they are printed.  You could always reorder the if/else if/else statement in my answer to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably way to go, any other component will do pretty much the same. Just a tip for save you some writing:

```
while ($r = $q->fetch()) {
  $i++;
  echo "<p style='color:" . ($i ==1 ? 'red': $i == $total? 'blue':'green') . ";'>" . $r['id'] . "</p>"; 
}
```

Comment: The selectors are better idea though, didn't think about that :)

Comment: Isnt this still 1000 IF statments?

Comment: It is, I don't see anything particularly wrong with using 1000 ifs here, that's the way it is. Or you have the CSS option. That was just ... cosmetic FIX :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pulling back a 1000 rows of data, why not make 2 sql calls? One to query for the first record:

```
SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM `table` LIMIT 0, 1000) tmp ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

And one for the second:

```
SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM `table` LIMIT 0, 1000) tmp ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thats what Im wondering...would 3 sql calls be more efficient than 1000 IF's?

Comment: Man, don't! This will be sloooooooooow :)

Comment: @supercoolville - No.  An `IF` is extremely trivial.  Connecting to a DB, authenticating, sending the sql string, parsing, processing and transferring the results back, all using network traffic multiple times, that sounds like a lot more than a few local CPU cycles to do IF statements.

Comment: The major difference is returning 1,000 rows back to the web application is going to be consume a lot more bandwidth and be a sql heavy process down the line if you make this call a lot.  If your are looking for a single trip to the DB you could use SELECT (SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM `table` LIMIT 0, 1000) tmp ORDER BY id LIMIT 1) as `first`,(SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM `table` LIMIT 0, 1000) tmp ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as `last`

Comment: If your ids are always guaranteed to be in order you could also use: SELECT MIN(id) as `first`,MAX(id) as `last` FROM (SELECT id FROM `table` LIMIT 0, 1000) tmp